# How can one force the browser to redraw an image?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, animation

I'm working on a JavaScript game that involves throwing a snowball. I need the snowball to render as often as possible during its flight path. Chrome does all the calculations, including setting the style.left and style.top properties, but doesn't actually redraw the snowball until it reaches its destination. Opera doesn't have this problem.

A relevant point is that putting in an `alert()` after `renderSnowball()` fixes the problem, except using the alert() is an obvious issue.

Here's my code so far:

```
function throwSnowball()
{
    var theta = parseFloat(angleField.value) *    Math.PI/180 ;
    var Vir = parseFloat(velocityField.value) ;

    if (!isNaN(Vir) && !isNaN(theta) )
    {

    Vix = Math.cos(theta) * Vir * 50;
    Viy = Math.sin(theta) * Vir * 50;   

time = new Date() ;
var timeThrown = time.getTime() ;

    while (snowballPosY > 0)
    {
        current = new Date() ;
        var currentTime = current.getTime() ;

        var timeElapsed = (currentTime - timeThrown)/5000 ;
        snowballPosX += Vix * timeElapsed;
        snowballPosY += Viy * timeElapsed;
        Viy -= GRAVITY * timeElapsed ;
        renderSnowball() ;      //renderSnowball() sets the style.left
                 // and style.top properties to snowballPosX pixels 
                 // and snowballPosY pixels respectively                        
        timeThrown = currentTime ;
    }

    snowballPosX = 0 ;
    snowballPosY = 50 ;
    renderSnowball() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `requestAnimationFrame` to move it, not a `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're totally blocking the main thread. Have you tried using a `setTimeout` (even with a zero timeout) to allow other things to happen during your animation?

If you're willing to use experimental technology, [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) would be even better.

Edit: the `setTimeout` approach would look something like this (replacing the `while` loop):

```
var drawAndWait = function() {
  if (snowballPosY > 0) {
    // movement/drawing code here
    setTimeout(drawAndWait, 20 /* milliseconds */);
  } else {
    // reset code that would normally go after your while loop
  }
};
drawAndWait();
```

So each time the drawing finishes, it arranges for itself to be invoked again, if appropriate. Note that your `throwSnowball` function will return quickly; the throwing isn't actually done until later on. This takes awhile to get used to doing correctly; don't be too concerned if it's not intuitive at first.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm very new to javascript (I have about a month) so i don't quite understand what you mean. Can you post a revision or an example of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting out of the tight loop. Chrome may not want to redraw until your function exits. Try using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to give Chrome a chance to repaint.